# Looping through products from a particular collection

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am using the following code to loop through products in the sidebar of the blog section of a website...

```
<ul>
{% for product in collections.all.products limit: 8 %}
 <li>
  <img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ product.title | escape  }}" />    
  <a class="shop-now" href="{{ product.url }}">{{ product.title | escape  }} 
  </a>                              
 </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I have looked for the solution to this but have turned up nothing... I would like to change the code to be able to specify the collection, so that it only loops through that specific collection.

But I would also like to use a plugin such as meta fields master to specify the collection for each blog post.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

`collection.all` refers to all products. Try with this below code. Ex: If your collection handle is abc-collection , below code with fetch first 8 products from the collection.

```
<ul>
{% for product in collections['abc-collection'].products limit: 8 %}
 <li>
  <img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ product.title | escape  }}" />    
  <a class="shop-now" href="{{ product.url }}">{{ product.title | escape  }} 
  </a>                              
 </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```